# Pandas column turns to `True` we select two values from other columns, when `False` select the same two values

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 time                    mid price  dse_high_born
18  2019-04-22 00:05:15 0.001854    False
19  2019-04-22 00:05:30 0.001854    False
20  2019-04-22 00:05:45 0.001854    False
21  2019-04-22 00:06:00 0.001854    False
22  2019-04-22 00:06:15 0.001854    True
23  2019-04-22 00:06:30 0.001854    True
24  2019-04-22 00:06:45 0.001854    True
25  2019-04-22 00:07:00 0.001856    True
26  2019-04-22 00:07:15 0.001856    True
27  2019-04-22 00:07:30 0.001856    True
28  2019-04-22 00:07:45 0.001856    True
29  2019-04-22 00:08:00 0.001856    False
30  2019-04-22 00:08:15 0.001856    False
```

So basically what I need is to iterate through the column `dse_high_born` when the column turns to `True`, select at the same row the value `Time` and `mid price` from the two other columns and add them into a new column `Time1` and `Price1` at the same index.

After that, when the column `dse_high_born` turns to `False` select the same two values (time, mid price) on the same row and add them at the same index in two new column `Time2` and `Price2`.

I tried to iterate and use the function `continue` but it did not work at all... I am a bit stuck! Any idea? Thanks in advance!

The results that I need would be something like that:

```
    time                    mid price  dse_high_born  Time1   price1  Time2 Price2
  2019-04-22 00:05:15 0.001854    False
  2019-04-22 00:05:30 0.001854    False
  2019-04-22 00:05:45 0.001854    False
  2019-04-22 00:06:00 0.001854    False
  2019-04-22 00:06:15 0.001854    True        2019-04-22 00:06:15 0.001854 
  2019-04-22 00:06:30 0.001854    True
  2019-04-22 00:06:45 0.001854    True
  2019-04-22 00:07:00 0.001856    True
  2019-04-22 00:07:15 0.001856    True
  2019-04-22 00:07:30 0.001856    True
  2019-04-22 00:07:45 0.001856    True                           2019-04-22 00:07:45 0.001856 
  2019-04-22 00:08:00 0.001856    False
  2019-04-22 00:08:15 0.001856    False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect value changes, use `shift()`:

```
changes = df['dse_high_born'].ne(df['dse_high_born'].shift()
```

and then:

```
changes_at_true = changes & df['dse_high_born']
changes_at_false = changes & ~df['dse_high_born']
```

gives changes occurs at `True` values. So you can do:

```
df.loc[changes_at_true, ['Time', 'mid_price']] += df.loc[changes_at_true, ['Time1', 'Price1']]
```

---

**Edit**: if you want to *copy* the values into new columns, do:

```
df['Time1'] = ''
df['Price1'] = ''

df.loc[changes_at_true, ['Time1', 'Price1']] = df.loc[changes_at_true, ['Time', 'mid_price']]
```

Comment: I just added an example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Unfortunately it updates the column with `Nan` for both... and also if you just see on the example I put above, it should also update the colum time1 and price1 when the column `dse_high_born` goes back to `False`! Thanks

Comment: @Viktor.w Change `None` to whatever you feel suit. You should be able to do the other two columns by defining `changes_at_false`, similar to `changes_at_true`.

Comment: Yes indeed it updates now but my time now became a super long number like ` 1555891575000000000 ` do you have an idea why?

Comment: Change the default value for 'Time1' and 'Time2' to 'pd.NaT'.

Comment: Yes it works thanks! but how do you do the changes_at_false? thanks!